# Linq Groupby Sum a nested observable collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need some help aggregating data in my collection.

The RrvResponse class

```
/// <summary>
    /// The RRV response.
    /// </summary>
    public class RrvResponse
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RrvResponse"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public RrvResponse()
        {
            this.BoDPoints = new ObservableCollection<BidOfferPoint>();    
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the id.
        /// </summary>
        public string Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the message date.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime MessageDate { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the BOD points.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<BidOfferPoint> BoDPoints { get; set; }
    }
```

The implementation,

```
var responses = new ObservableCollection<RrvResponse>();

// ....Load responses...
// ...
// ...
```

The count of responses is 5, So I have 5 ObservableCollection of BoDPoints inside responses.

```
BOD points are,

    /// <summary>
        /// The bid offer point.
        /// </summary>
        public class BidOfferPoint
        {

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the date.
            /// </summary>
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the time.
            /// </summary>
            public string Time { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the volume.
            /// </summary>
            public decimal Volume { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the price.
            /// </summary>
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
        }
```

Sample,

```
Observable Collection Bod - 1
2013-06-21 
00:00
100
10

2013-06-21
00:15
120
15

2013-06-21
00:30
150
9
```

Observable Collection Bod - 2

```
2013-06-21 
00:00
Observable Collection Bod - 1
2013-06-21 
00:00
100
10

2013-06-21
00:15
120
15

2013-06-21
00:30
150
9
40
1

2013-06-21
00:15
10
0.5

2013-06-21
00:30
11
0.1
```

Observable Collection Bod - 3

```
2013-06-15 
00:00
100
10

2013-06-15
00:15
120
15

2013-06-15
00:30
150
9
```

I would like to group by date then hours across the collection and aggregate the volumes. So in the above example all volumes for 21-06-2013 for hour 00:00 should be aggregated, all volumes for 21-06-2013 for hour 00:15 should be aggregated.

What is the best approach using Linq to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to aggregate the items and group them afterwards:

```
var result = responses
    .SelectMany(r => r.BoDPoints)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Date)
    .Select(byDate => 
        new 
        {
            Date = byDate.Key,
            EntriesByTime = byDate
                .GroupBy(p => p.Time)
                .Select(byTime => 
                    new 
                    {
                        Time = byTime.Key,
                        TotalVolume = byTime.Sum(p => p.Volume)
                    })
        });
```

You can use the following loop (e.g. to output the total volume)

```
foreach (var byDate in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entries for date " + byDate.Date);
    foreach (var byTime in byDate.EntriesByTime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Total volume for time " + byTime.Time + ": " + byTime.TotalVolume);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get the sum of volumes?